# How do you completely uninstall old versions of gazebo?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, I am new to gazebo, and I am trying to install gazebo through Homebrew on Mac OSX 10.8.5.  I had an error when I installed gazebo 1.9.5, so rather than try to fix this error (which I think was just a missing program), I installed gazebo --HEAD, which I think should have given me gazebo 3.0.  I compiled gazebo using catkin as instructed, but now this happens:

```
dhcp-5-248:~ gunnar$ gazebo
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.9.5
Copyright (C) 2014 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master.Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.9.5
Copyright (C) 2014 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Warning [ModelDatabase.cc:335] Getting models from[http://gazebosim.org/models/]. This may take a few seconds.
....Warning [ModelDatabase.cc:206] Unable to connect to model database using [http://gazebosim.org/models//database.config]. Only locally installed models will be available.
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:408] Unable to download model[model://sun]
Error [SystemPaths.cc:371] File or path does not exist[""]
Error [parser.cc:528] Unable to find uri[model://sun]
Warning [ModelDatabase.cc:335] Getting models from[http://gazebosim.org/models/]. This may take a few seconds.
.....Warning [ModelDatabase.cc:206] Unable to connect to model database using [http://gazebosim.org/models//database.config]. Only locally installed models will be available.
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:408] Unable to download model[model://ground_plane]
Error [SystemPaths.cc:371] File or path does not exist[""]
Error [parser.cc:528] Unable to find uri[model://ground_plane]
Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 192.168.5.248
2014-04-18 10:22:56.839 gzserver[56504:707] invalid drawable

Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 192.168.5.248
2014-04-18 10:22:57.711 gzclient[56505:707] invalid drawable
2014-04-18 10:23:00.146 gzclient[56505:707] invalid drawable
Warning [ModelDatabase.cc:206] Unable to connect to model database using [http://gazebosim.org/models//database.config]. Only locally installed models will be available.
```

It appears as if gazebo is still 1.9.5.  Sometimes I am able to connect to master, but most of the time I am not.  How do I get rid of the older versions of gazebo?  Or is there another problem that I should fix?

Homebrew doctor gives no warnings or errors.

Thank you for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5971/how-do-you-completely-uninstall-old-versions-of-gazebo?/) by [gunnar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/747/gunnar/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-04-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2014-04-20**:
Can you post the output of the following commands: `brew info sdformat`, `brew info gazebo`, `which gazebo`? This will help with debugging. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo requires an internet connection in order to download model files (such as the sun and ground plane for the default world). If you don't internet access the first time you run gazebo, it will give this error. One option is to manually download model files from gazebosim.org/models and put them in your `~/.gazebo/models` folder. Another option is to clone to the https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models repository and place its location in the `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH` environment variable. Let me know if this works for you.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gunnar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/747/gunnar/) on 2014-04-29**:
Ok, thanks for your help!  It seems to be working now. I have the models in the folder by cloning them.  It must have been a combination of internet error on the first run and some other problem that must have resolved itself after rebuilding.